# How to look for specific values in a dictionary and return them properly

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, iteration, dictionary-comprehension

So I have a list dictionary of dictionaries (lst) that I'm trying to iterate through, compare values, and return the appropriate values.

I have the following code to retrieve 2 arguments given from the command line, compare them through the dictionaries entries, and return the appropriate value:

```
def get_attribute_number(cmd1, cmd2, lst):

    app_name = cmd1
    attribute = cmd2
    for name in lst: #lst is a dictionary
        if name["description"] == app_name:
            print(int(name[attribute]))
```

`get_attribute_number(cmd1=sys.argv[1], cmd2=sys.argv[2], lst=data_list)`

However, my program is not returning anything. It is supposed to for example if I provide the cmd line arguments `python3 program.py [NAME] [ATTRIBUTE]`, is supposed to query the above data until it finds a match for the name, and return its requested attribute as an integer. Can anyone offer suggestions on why I'm not able to `print(int(name[attribute]))` for the corresponding `napp_name`?

Comment: `"['kytos/kytos']"` is not equal to `"kytos/kytos"`

Comment: @jakubDóka even if I cast it (str()) into a string nothing happens. Any suggestions on how to turn "['kytos/kytos']" into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changes your code a little to be more friendly to user:

```
import sys

data_list = [{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/kytos']", '{#PASSED}': '316', '{#FAILED}': '1', '{#WARNING}': '204', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/python-openflow']", '{#PASSED}': '400', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': 0, '{#SKIPPED}': '40', '{#XFAILED}': '1'},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/of_core']", '{#PASSED}': '49', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '39', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/kytos-utils']", '{#PASSED}': '102', '{#FAILED}': '2', '{#WARNING}': 0, '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/mef_eline']", '{#PASSED}': '102', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '88', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/flow_manager']", '{#PASSED}': '36', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '22', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/topology']", '{#PASSED}': '58', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '56', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/kronos']", '{#PASSED}': '61', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '21', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/pathfinder']", '{#PASSED}': 0, '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': 0, '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/status']", '{#PASSED}': '81', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '1', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/of_l2ls']", '{#PASSED}': '7', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '7', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/of_lldp']", '{#PASSED}': '17', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '17', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['success']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/maintenance']", '{#PASSED}': '28', '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': '28', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/storehouse']", '{#PASSED}': '63', '{#FAILED}': '1', '{#WARNING}': '32', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0},
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/kytos-end-to-end-tester']", '{#PASSED}': 0, '{#FAILED}': 0, '{#WARNING}': 0, '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0}]

def get_attribute_number(cmd1, cmd2, lst):
    """For each attribute under a napp, retrieve that attribute as a NUMBER"""
    napp_name = cmd1
    attribute_name = cmd2
    for napp in lst: #lst is a dictionary
        if napp_name in napp["{#DESCRIPTION}"]: # change happened here
            print(napp)
            print(int(napp[attribute_name]))

get_attribute_number(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], data_list)
```

basicly thay need to enter just substring to get some results, so this:

```
python tt.py 'kytos/kytos' {#SKIPPED}
```

outputs only desired data:

```
{'{#Status}': "['failed']", '{#DESCRIPTION}': "['kytos/kytos']", '{#PASSED}': '316', '{#FAILED}': '1', '{#WARNING}': '204', '{#SKIPPED}': 0, '{#XFAILED}': 0}
0
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding conversion to string: you can try, to evaluate the expression that will give you a list; if the format is always the same you can also use regex:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(napp["{#DESCRIPTION}"])[0]
```

so in your case:

```
import ast
def get_attribute_number(cmd1, cmd2, lst):
    """For each attribute under a napp, retrieve that attribute as a NUMBER"""
    napp_name = cmd1
    attribute_name = cmd2
    for napp in lst: #lst is a dictionary
        if ast.literal_eval(napp["{#DESCRIPTION}"])[0] == napp_name:
            print(int(napp[attribute_name]))
```